# & symbol in xml

Tags: xml, rss, symbols

I'm working with a xml file which fails when opening it in firefox. I'm getting an interpretation error. Its all because of the & symbol. When replacing it with`&amp`; or removing it i get no error.

The problem is that the receiver of this xml document who prints it out on their homepage prints out `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Can i do something or should they do something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XML, `&` by itself is not allowed. You need to escape it to `&amp;` or  place it in a `<![CDATA[]]>` section.

Your reciever is treating XML as if it was normal text - they are not doing the right thing.

However, if they can't change, you can use `<![CDATA[&]]>` for the ampersand, though if they don't treat the data as XML, it will probably also cause them problems (but be more explicit).

A third option is to encode the `&` as its numeric character entity `&#38;` - this may work if the reciever treats XML as HTML, but if they display it as `&#38;`, they need to fix it on their end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the numeric representation for &, which is `&#38;`, may be the receiver just does not understand the entities.

If this does not help, than it is definitely receiver's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox fails because & is the start of an entity in XML, and it expects the rest of an entity.

If you want to send the symbol &, you should replace `&` with its entity `&amp;` or `&#38;`  or either send an unparsed string with `CDATA`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA